# automate timed button click on a webpage

Tags: browser, mfc, httpwebrequest, c++-cli

Basically my goal is to be able to navigate to a webpage that contains a button. This button is not enabled or active until a certain amount of time(java script function I believe). I have no problem access webpages automatically as I've done that before but I have yet to learn to automate a button click. I've looked on the web and it seems clicking a button can be accomplished with httpwebrequest's POST ability or using a webbrowser control but It seems that requires the use of a GUI which I don't want. So can this be accomplished? And how would I go about loading the webpage and waiting for the button to be enabled before automating the click?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even i was looking for similar stuff.
Hopefully this link might help you out https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/

I am making something if it works out will post all the details